# Tensorboard refuses to show logs

Tags: python, tensorboard

I have trained a CNN model and saved tensorboard log files that are in the folders logs/acl/sagittal/ and the last folders are several numered folders where the actual log files reside.

I've tried to view them using:

tensorboard --logdir logs

Resulting in:

```
(Pytorch) C:\Users\GlaDOS>tensorboard --logdir logs
C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:541: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:542: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:543: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:544: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:545: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
2020-07-16 13:16:27.702008: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-07-16 13:16:27.702133: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
TensorBoard 1.14.0 at http://DESKTOP-67DAOD4:6006/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Entering http://DESKTOP-67DAOD4:6006/ shows a text: No dashboards are active for the current data set.

Trying to look at different views always show "no data". I'm supposed to get a result like [this.](https://www.ahmedbesbes.com/static/2aff315794096b445658fb9ec5d3d07d/b9e4f/sagittal_tensorboard.png)

`tensorboard --inspect --logdir logs` also shows "no event files" but it also says they are supposed to be detected even if nested in subdirs? Even if I try to navigate to a subdir it gives the same message.

If I try to navigate the exact path: `tensorboard --inspect --logdir "C:\Users\GlaDOS\mrnet\logs`" I get:

```
(Pytorch) C:\Users\GlaDOS>tensorboard --inspect --logdir="C:\Users\GlaDOS\mrnet\logs"
C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:541: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:542: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:543: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:544: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:545: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
2020-07-16 13:30:05.700038: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-07-16 13:30:05.700168: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
======================================================================
Processing event files... (this can take a few minutes)
======================================================================

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\Scripts\tensorboard-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(run_main())
  File "C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\main.py", line 64, in run_main
    app.run(tensorboard.main, flags_parser=tensorboard.configure)
  File "C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\program.py", line 222, in main
    efi.inspect(self.flags.logdir, event_file, self.flags.tag)
  File "C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\event_processing\event_file_inspector.py", line 403, in inspect
    inspection_units = get_inspection_units(logdir, event_file, tag)
  File "C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\event_processing\event_file_inspector.py", line 362, in get_inspection_units
    for f in tf.io.gfile.listdir(subdir)
  File "C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\event_processing\event_file_inspector.py", line 363, in <listcomp>
    if io_wrapper.IsTensorFlowEventsFile(os.path.join(subdir, f))
  File "C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\event_processing\event_file_inspector.py", line 337, in generator_from_event_file
    return event_file_loader.EventFileLoader(event_file).Load()
  File "C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\event_processing\event_file_loader.py", line 42, in __init__
    self._reader = _pywrap_tensorflow.PyRecordReader_New(
  File "C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\lazy.py", line 65, in __getattr__
    return getattr(load_once(self), attr_name)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow' has no attribute 'PyRecordReader_New'
```

And this is probably a more "correct" error since I also get the same error if I cd into the file folder before accessing tensorboard as before.

I'm trying to complete [this tutorial](https://www.ahmedbesbes.com/blog/acl-tear-detection-part-2).